# Swift static value stuck at original value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state

Can someone tell me why my static variable isn't changing when I use a += on it? I have been stuck on this bug for a while.

```
    @State static var counter:Int = 2
    @State static var increment:Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: " + String(ContentView.counter))
            Button(action:  {
                ContentView.counter += ContentView.increment
            print(ContentView.counter)
```

Comment: Why are you using `@State` on a `static var`? Why aren't those instance properties?

Comment: wdym? Im a bit of a noob.

Comment: Remote `static`, just do `@State private var counter: Int = 2` and `@State private var increment: Int = 1`. Also, all `@State` properties __must__ be private, so make those private.

Comment: But I want to use the variable between multiple views 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share state between different instances of your view, you should inject said state as a `Binding` rather than declaring an `@State static` property inside the `View`.

`@State` properties should only be updated from inside the (body of the) view itself, which isn't the case if you declare an `@State` property as `static`. To ensure the update can only happen from inside the `View`, all `@State` properties **must be `private`** (or at the very least `private(set)`).

Not sure how exactly you create different instances of your view, but here's an example of how you could introduce shared state between them in a correct way:

```
struct Cell: View {
    @Binding private var counter: Int
    @Binding private var increment: Int

    init(counter: Binding<Int>, increment: Binding<Int>) {
        self._counter = counter
        self._increment = increment
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: \(counter)")
            Button("Increment by \(increment)", action: { counter += increment })
        }
    }
}

struct Counter: View {
    @State private var counter: Int = 2
    @State private var increment: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Cell(counter: $counter, increment: $increment)
            Cell(counter: $counter, increment: $increment)
            Cell(counter: $counter, increment: $increment)
        }
    }
}
```